# Accessing property of function using its object in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

How to access properties in oop javascript via object, I am getting     following error : "Uncaught TypeError: x.firstname is not a function
at newindex.html:19"

How do I access firstname using x object

```
 function person() {
    this.firstName = "hello";
 }

 var x = new person();
 console.log(x.firstname());// how to get firstname from x ??
```

Comment: `x.firstName`, without extra `()`.

Comment: You might want to read a JavaScript tutorial to learn the basics about objects: http://eloquentjavascript.net/ .

Answer (score 1):

`firstName` should be with captital letter N and accessed without parenthesis.

Change this line:

```
console.log(x.firstname());// how to get firstname from x ??
```

To this line:

```
console.log(x.firstName);// how to get firstname from x ??
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstname is a property, not a function so including parentheses at the end is what is creating your error. You are also not case matching your variables `firstname != firstName`. Here is an example of accessing a property and also a function.

```js
function Person() {
    this.firstName = "hello";
    this.firstNameFunc = function() { return 'function exec' };
}
let person = new Person();
console.log(person.firstName);
console.log(person.firstNameFunc());
```

Answer (score 0):

**`firstName`** is a **`property`** , not a function. You should do,

```
console.log(x.firstName);
```

DEMO

```js
function person() {
    this.firstName = "hello";
 }

 var x = new person();
 console.log(x.firstName);
```

Comment: Properties can have function values and the properties name is `firstName` (capital `N`). It's more correct to simply say "`firstName` is a string, not a function".